# yum install ERROR

Tags: fedora, yum

```
yum install ruby Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit

http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml:
[Errno 12] Timeout on
http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Everything/i386/os/repodata/repomd.xml:
(28, 'Connection timed out after 30001 milliseconds') Trying other
mirror.
```

This is what is happening whenever i try to install something on my fedora 20 system

Comment: Those mirror are not working. remove those .repo and install these from `rpm fusion` site `yum install --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm`

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 20 is [EOL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/End_of_life) for almost a year and the mirrors providing updates are not working anymore.

Update to some supported version, such as Fedora 23 or 24 (just released).

Answer (score 0):

---

If you have a very good reason for using Fedora 20 : 1) Move all repo files in /etc/yum.repos.d to a backup folder. 2) Use this fedora20.repo, which points to "the old archive" :

```
[fedora20]
name=Fedora20-i386 
baseurl=http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/20/Everything/i386/os/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1

[fc20-updates]
name=Fedora20-updates-i386
baseurl=http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/20/i386/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

---